# Colunas no Bootstrap não está funcionando

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando colocar a logomarca da empresa do lado esquerdo e o título do lado direito com Bootstrap, mas não está funcionando. Quando coloco o código abaixo, fica um embaixo do outro. Estou usando a versão 4.0. Vejam:

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #54310B;background-image: url('images/b1.jpg');min-height: 280px; text-align:left;">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/logo.png" style="width: 180px; margin-top: 80px; z-index: 99999999999; position: relative;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">Nossa História</div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esqueceu de inserir o `.row`, então ficaria deste modo:

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #54310B;background-image: url('images/b1.jpg');min-height: 280px; text-align:left;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 1px red solid;">
                <img src="images/logo.png" style="width: 180px; margin-top: 80px; z-index: 99999999999; position: relative;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8" style="border: 1px red solid;">Nossa História</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Ilustração de como ficará (do modo que pediu)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito Thiago. Funcionou. Tentei dar como aceite sua resposta, mas tenho que esperar 5 minutos. Assim que passar esse tempo, marcarei como a resposta correta. Obrigado!

Comment: @Fox.11 tudo bem, fico no aguardo. Obrigado você!